# Access LinkedObjects in lists

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm working on an iOS project and using Realm for the first time. Basically, my realm objects are something like:

```
class Account: Object
{
   @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId = ObjectId.generate()
   @Persisted var name : String = ""
   let administers = LinkingObjects(fromType: Group, property: "administrator")
}

class Group
{
    @Persisted var administrator = Account?
}
```

I would like to add the functionality of a Group to have several "mantainers", ie. Accounts that can access certain Group/Groups without them being the administrators. In other words, an Account can administer several groups and also can maintain groups administered by some other Account.

I was thinking of adding the property `@Persisted var mantainers = [Account?]` to the `Group` object but I'm not sure is the right approach. Also, I wouldn't know later how to access the maintained groups from an `Account`.

Is there a way to do this or am I just a bit lost and this is not the right approach?

Comment: Sorry for this
`@Persisted var owns = LinkingObjects(fromType: Group, property: "owner")
`
it would actually be something like
`let owns = LinkingObject(fromType: Group, property: "owner")`

Comment: Can you  remove that comment and just update the question with that info?

Comment: I would not use the word 'owns' or 'owner' here as that is not what a linking object does or is. Linking objects are calculated paths to other objects. In other words, you don't add an object to a LinkingObjects property - whereas you would add an object to a List property but even at that, the parent object doesn't own it. Several objects can add a certain object to their List property. From there, the question is a bit vague - are you trying to give several different object classes access to Group objects?

Comment: Hey Jay, thanks for your answer. the word "owner" has to do with "real-world" context and semantics, not with implementation assumptions, updated the question with the comments you made to hopefully be clearer

Comment: As is, you can transverse the object graph from a Group back to a specific Account (via the administers property). If you were to add another property to the Group, say `group_manager` and then add a LinkingObject property `managed_groups` to the Account for that, you could then do the same thing from groups back to their group_manager. Then, an Account could manage the groups in their administrators property as well as the managed_groups property. Perhaps updating the question with what kind of queries you want to run would help clarify it.